# Character Table and Binary Basis

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, mathematics

This is the character table for the group $C_{3}$

[image]

The last column represents the binary basis corresponding to different irrep, But I did not understand from where we are getting this basis ($x^2+y^2, yz$, etc.). Could you please explain this? Is there a rigorous way of getting this?

Reference: Group Theory for Physicists: With Applications
Book by Pichai Ramadevi and Varun Dubey

Comment: This question is more suited to [math.se] since it does not involve any physics. See [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/should-pure-math-questions-be-on-topic).

Comment: It could be that it actually is about physics and this "binary basis" is about qubit states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, but I think the precise meaning can only come from the text of the document where this table is coming from. (And OP did unfortunately not provide any of that information).

Comment: Reference: Group Theory for Physicists: With Applications
Book by Pichai Ramadevi and Varun Dubey

Answer (score 1):

The final column is obtained by representing the abstract group as an isometry subgroup. Each set of quadratic polynomials (separated by a semicolon) span an irreducible representation whose type is given by the line of the table. In the case of spectroscopy, this is the representation that you are interested in the first place as it captures the point group symmetry of the molecule. The quadratic functions are relevant for understanding the quadrupole interactions with the EM field and allows you to check whether the molecule is Raman active.

For example, your group can be seen as the subgroup of the three rotations multiple of a third turn about the $z$ axis: $\{1,r,r^2\}$ with
$$
r=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac12 & -\frac{\sqrt 3}2 & 0 \\ \frac{\sqrt 3}2 & -\frac12 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
You can make it act on the 6D space of quadratic polynomial by composition (the inverse is there to preserve the order for the left action):
$$
g[P]=P\circ g^{-1}
$$
The representation decomposes into 4 irreducible representations.

For example, after a third of a turn:
$$
x^2-y^2\to \frac{(-x+\sqrt3y)^2-(-\sqrt3x-y)^2}4=-\frac12(x^2-y^2)-\sqrt3xy\\
xy\to\frac{(-x+\sqrt3y)(-\sqrt3x-y)}4=\frac{\sqrt3}4(x^2-y^2)-\frac12xy
$$
so $(x^2-y^2,xy)$ do span a stable subset and the induced representation is the standard representation: $E$. You can check that it has the same matrix form if you correctly normalize the basis to $(2xy,x^2-y^2)$.

Hope this helps.